# DataBind to Combobox In SilverLight 4 .0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to databind to the combobox. Data is coming from a database table which name is tbltest and table has 2 fileds id and name.

When I am trying to bind name to combox it display me tbltest:name in View. I am using domain services and MVVM to bind data.

Below is my code of ViewModel:

```
   public ViewModel()
    {
        var query = context.GetTblTestsQuery();
        var load = context.Load(query);
        load.Completed += (s, ea) =>
        {
            ObsCompanyCollection = new ObservableCollection<tblTest>(context.tblTests);

        };

    }
  private ObservableCollection<tblTest> _ObsCompanyCollection = new ObservableCollection<tblTest>();     
    public ObservableCollection<tblTest> ObsCompanyCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _ObsCompanyCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ObsCompanyCollection != value)
            {
                _ObsCompanyCollection = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ObsCompanyCollection");
            }
        }

    }
```

and Below is code of my XAml file:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <my:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">


    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,128,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding name,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding ObsCompanyCollection,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding tbldata.SelectCompanyId,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I dont know what is wrong with this code. I want only name to display in my combobox.

Thanks

Comment: Change the display member path to, DisplayMemberPath="name"

Comment: Thanks for ur reply...Its wroking fine but i want to save id of selected item into another table tbldata. so how can i get id of seleted item. when I save data it store as null.

Comment: To get selected value, var x = (Your itemssource object)combobox.SelectedItem;

Comment: Thanks again.Now its wroking.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,128,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath="name" ItemsSource="{Binding ObsCompanyCollection,Mode=OneWay}"
```